# JLS: section 5.2 Assignment Conversion (chain of conversions)

Tags: java, jls

I'm trying to understand the example from JLS.

[This section reads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> **It is a compile-time error if the chain of conversions contains two parametrized types that are not in the subtype relation.**
>
> An example of such an illegal chain would be:
>
> ```
> Integer, Comparable<Integer>, Comparable, Comparable<String>
> ```
>
> The first three elements of the chain are related by widening
>   reference conversion, while the last entry is derived from its
>   predecessor by unchecked conversion. However, this is not a valid
>   assignment conversion, because the chain contains two parametrized
>   types, `Comparable<Integer>` and `Comparable<String>`, that are not
>   subtypes.

In what conditions we cat get this chain? Can somebody give some more verbose example?

Comment: You can't get it under any conditions. It is not allowed by the language.

Comment: specification said, that we can get compile-time error, so I would like to look at the code that саuses this error.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the JLS. I also don't know what they mean by _chain_ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've made some sense of it.

Assignment contexts apply to assignment expressions.

In the expressions

```
Integer integerValue = 42;
Comparable<Integer> comparableInteger = integerValue;
```

the integer literal `42` can be assigned to a variable of type `Integer` through a boxing conversion. A value of type `Integer` can be assigned to a variable of type `Comparable<Integer>` through widening reference conversion.

In the following expression

```
Comparable raw = comparableInteger;
```

a value of type `Comparable<Integer>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Comparable` through widening reference conversion.

But you cannot do

```
Comparable<String> comparableString = integerValue;
```

because that would require an unchecked conversion from `Comparable` to `Comparable<String>`, which is not necessarily bad, except when

> the chain of conversions contains two parametrized types that are not in
>   the subtype relation

You could have done

```
Comparable raw = comparableInteger;
Comparable<String> parameterized = raw;
```

and that will use unchecked conversion (and potentially a `ClassCastException` at runtime when you try to invoke `compareTo`). However, there is no issue at compile time because the chain of conversions was simply

```
Comparable, Comparable<String>
```

which is allowed.